# How to add a DataRow to a DataTable in a Viewmodel via multithreading

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm, binding, datatable

I got a problem with the designpattern MVVM.
In my View i got a Datagrid with an binding to a datatable in my viewmodel.

```
        <WPF:BADataGrid Grid.Column="1" x:Name="dgStapelliste" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Stapelliste, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

In my constructor of the viewmodel I load the ItemsSource.

```
        this.StapelListe = this._stapel.Get();
```

If I add some additional rows during runtime via a button everything works fine.
But I don´t want to push a button to refresh the datagrid, I want it to happen automatically in a thread or background worker.

Here´s some test example:

```
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);

                DataRow row = this.StapelListe.NewRow();
                row["StapelNr"] = 123456;
                this.StapelListe.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        };
```

THIS won´t work... and I don´t know why... the rows are added in the datatable "StapelListe" but the datagrid is not going to refresh itself...

If I change an existing row in the datatable in a thread it works! It just doesn´t work with adding or removing rows from the collection.

Someone got an idea why this happens and/or how to resolve it?

Kind regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MegaMind wrote, the View needs to know that something has changed. If you are adding new Rows to an existing DataTable, the View never gets notified that something has been added. So you should use a collection which was made for that: `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: Yes ObservableCollection will definitely work, but he is having a datatable, to use observable collection he needs to loop through the entire datatable and get required collection out of it, Big Overhead I guess.

Comment: @MegaMind Yes, he will have to transform the DataTable to an ObservableCollection. But I don't think it will be such a big overhead. Instead, that is what a ViewModel is for: Transforming the Model data (in this case a DataTable) to something the View understands properly (in this case an ObservableCollection).

Comment: Fully agree with you, either he has to use observable collection or need to change the reference of the list, in case he wants to stick with the list. In case of List he has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, with observable collection he'll do just fine with out that interface.

Comment: Thank you guys!!! I did it with the ObservableCollection now. It´s doing exactly what I want!

Answer (score 2):

You make the classic mistake of databinding. How should you suppose your screens update, if you never let your GUI know that something changes. to do this you need to use **NotifyPropertyChanged** interface.

Implement your viewmodel from INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

This is a code snippet that could you put at work

You don't have to use the thread to make this work, anything will just fine as long as you call NotifyProperyChanged after updating your collection.

In case you are not using ObservableCollection, you have to update the reference of the list, which will be little painful to you app;s performance

```
     BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += delegate(object s, DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                DataRow row = this.StapelListe.NewRow();
                row["StapelNr"] = 123456;
                this.StapelListe.Rows.Add(row);
                Datatable dt=new datatable(); //new reference
                foreach (DataRow dr in StapelListe.Rows)
                {     
                 dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
                }

                 StapelList=dt; //updating the reference of property
                 // when the above line executes your property setter fires
                 // and calls notifyproperty changed and then all done
        };
```

Comment: yea... i tried it to raise the propertychanged event in the thread... but that won´t work either. gives me the same result

Comment: The problem with this approach is if you call PropertyChanged for the underlying DataTable, it means the View will have to redo the entire display of the DataTable's data. If you use an ObservableCollection, it will only need to update the actual changed data.